# writing scala spark code on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

the error that i am facing is

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar' in project 'sparkexamples' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file sparkexamples       Build path  Build Path Problem


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error in Scala compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.  sparkexamples       Unknown Scala Problem


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error while loading <root>, Error accessing C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-common\2.2.0\hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar  sparkexamples       Unknown Scala Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.'. Check Error Log for details. sparkexamples       Unknown Scala Problem
```

i am using scala 2.11.8

Comment: The error `cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file` tells you what the problem is. Try to remove the cached file (I would delete the directory `C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/` altogether). This may have been caused by some incomplete download...

Comment: should i be removing .m2 directory?

Comment: your choice, but I would just try deleting `.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/` first then retry, to see if that resolves it.

Comment: deleting .m2 worked for me.